# How to find the location name within the range of road distance circle?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, api

I am using this code to find the min max latlong of locations that fall under the radius of 200 km (i.e. Road distance from a specific point). But it returns the result on the base of the radial distance, not road distance. Can anyone help me get rid of this problem?

```
<?php

$lat = 28.6663433;
$long = 77.067959;
$radius = 200; // Kilometers
$earth_radius = 6371;

$lat_max = $lat + rad2deg($radius / $earth_radius);
$long_max = $long + rad2deg($radius / $earth_radius / cos(deg2rad($lat)));

$lat_min = $lat - rad2deg($radius / $earth_radius);
$long_min = $long - rad2deg($radius / $earth_radius / cos(deg2rad($lat)));


echo 'max lat: '.$lat_max.'<br/>';
echo 'max long: '.$long_max.'<br/>';
echo 'min lat: '.$lat_min.'<br/>';
echo 'min lat: '.$long_min.'<br/>';

?>
```

Comment: find google map api here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

For ROAD distance, you can take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests, there are different examples:

```
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
var origin2 = "Greenwich, England";
var destinationA = "Stockholm, Sweden";
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087692, 14.421150);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin1, origin2],
    destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    transitOptions: TransitOptions,
    drivingOptions: DrivingOptions,
    unitSystem: UnitSystem,
    avoidHighways: Boolean,
    avoidTolls: Boolean,
  }, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  // See Parsing the Results for
  // the basics of a callback function.
}
```

You will need an API Key.